# How to use vue-router to show different views of a data table

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

My web app shows a table of data as the primary view and one of the columns is "item-type". We also need to be able to show alternate versions of the table, limited to each item type.

For example, the main grid shows list all items in the table. But the "red" version only shows the items with the "item-type" of "red". And green shows only green, etc.

Then, in the menu, we need to show counts for how many are in each category - red (3), green (14), etc.

Our primary grid is a slightly modified version of the [example](https://v1.vuejs.org/examples/grid-component.html) from vuejs.org.

My assumption is that I need to create a new filter in the grid component to limit data by "item-type", and then use vue-router to dynamically link to each of those views. Is that the correct way to solve the problem? I can't find any documentation or examples or how to even get started.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: create a watcher to watch the url, and map it to the data structure of the table. Similiar example can be found http://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html

Comment: You should use computed properties as described [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties), where the computed property returns the filtered data.